# Why might we use "from . import * " in Python

Tags: python

what is the full meaning for this statement in python ?

```
from . import *
```

I have seen such code in some application like this one for minecraft map file reader.

https://github.com/twoolie/NBT/blob/master/nbt/__init__.py

Comment: import everything defined  in `__all__ =`

Comment: You should read the [documentation on this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

Comment: it's "from current directory import everything"

Comment: Typically though, I would just load what you need.

Answer (score 5):

When you write `from mypkg import *`, Python looks at the `__all__` variable of the `__init__.py` file of the package, which is believed to be filled with names of submodules. It then loads all the submodules listed in that variable into the local namespace. If `__all__` does not exist, it loads instead all the symbols defined in the `__init__.py` file (including submodules explicitely imported in that file, but not every submodule of the package). [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).

You use `from .` when you are in a submodule *inside* a package (intra-package reference). This refers to the package the submodule is in, whatever name it has. So `from . import *` does exactly what is described above, but for the package the submodule is part of. Note that if the submodule is itself listed in the `__all__` variable, then it will fail due to dependency loop.

Concerning your example, the module is itself the `__init__.py` and also defines a `__all__` variable, so it is lucky that Python doesn't crash on dependency loop. The line is useless anyway, as the local code doesn't make use of these modules.